# Why I can not access Google services on either Debian 64 bit or Debian 32 bit Linux Operating System

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, chrome

Problems describe in this question belongs to Debian 64 bit version of Linux operating system, running on Raspberry Pi 3 & 4 B+ Same services can be access on IE explorer on different machines as explain below:

[image]

I have tried to access google Chrome services from Debian 32 bit and Debian 64 bit I was unsuccessful in all my attempts but when I am trying to access same services from IE explorer I can access to all my reported services

Problem with Sync

[image]

When clicking on man icon in browser you get following login slide popup

[image]

In normal circumstances "Turn on Sync" (TOS) bar color is blue but in my case it is dark gray and when I click on TOS bar it's ask me to sign in but when I enter my google username and password it let me sign in to my google browser but does not restore my previously saved bookmarks, password and usernames etc.

After sign into the browser when I click on application icon and select Drive to access your google drive it will present you another page to enter your username and password after doing this step it will open google drive in browser but

[image]

with in couple of second it will appear with following popup:

[image]

Now if you click on Sign back in link new browser window will appear and ask you to enter your login details again

username window:

[image]

Password:

[image]

After completing this task authentication browser tab close itself and you automatically return to your google drive page but after couple of second before you click on any of your saved file the same following pop-up message appear back on your screen

[image]

and when you click on authentication link again it will take you back to your google drive page and then after couple of second same pop-up will appear again and again i.e i am unable to do anything in my Chrome browser.

I have even tried to access google Chrome services from Ubuntu, Debian 32 bit and Debian 64 bit but did get anywhere I was unsuccessful in all attempts

Can someone please suggest what I should do to recover my information back

Comment: Unfortunately Google dropped support for synching with 3rd party browsers on March 15, 2021.

Comment: So what are my option how can I get back to normal?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings 's corresponding announce: https://blog.chromium.org/2021/01/limiting-private-api-availability-in.html

Comment: It looks like Google distributes only i386 or amd64 deb binaries, not armhf/arm64. Emulation would be slow if it even worked. Can't see a solution to get Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found part solution to above problem

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am still unable to "Turn on Sync" because of the facts reported "Google dropped support for synching with 3rd party browsers on March 15, 2021." – by fuzzy drawings

and "corresponding announce: blog.chromium.org/2021/01/…" by – A.B in above comments

As soon as I have upgraded my RPI4 by using above command I am no longer facing following screen:

[image]

Now I can login to my Google account by typing my username and password

[image]

[image]

and then from application icon I can access my Google Drive

[image]

Without getting stuck in endless sign in and sign back loop

[image]

till I don't find solution to Sync I will import my bookmarks from IE

I know it's not the best solution but it is working for me at this moment
and I hope it will work for someone else too